# How to sort a List of Object by date in String format?

Tags: list, sorting, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have a List that have a parameter called updatedAt, it's a String that has the `DateTime.now().toString().substring(0, 19)` and I need to organize the by date (newest (position 0) to the oldest(last position)) but when I tried to use `list.sort((a, b) => a.updatedAt.compareTo(b.updatedAt))` I have the error below, do I have to convert the String to DateTime or something?

```
class Product {

  String id;
  String image;
  String name;
  String desc;
  int price;
  int quantity;
  String category;
  String createdAt;
  String updatedAt;
  bool active;

  Product({this.id, this.image, this.name, this.desc, this.price, this.quantity,
    this.category, this.createdAt, this.updatedAt, this.active}){
    quantity = 1;
    active = true;
  }

  Future<void> getProducts() async {

        List<Product> products = [];

        products.addAll(await getProductsFromFirestore()); // Here I add products from Firebase...

        print(products[0].updatedAt); // 2020-07-21 12:31:08
        print(products[1].updatedAt); // 2020-07-21 12:31:13
    
        products.sort((a, b) => a.updatedAt.compareTo(b.updatedAt));

  }
```

**Error (Flutter Web):**

```
Error: Expected a value of type 'Comparable<dynamic>', but got one of type 'Product'
at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:53122/dart_sdk.js:4339:11)
at Object.castError (http://localhost:53122/dart_sdk.js:4310:15)
at Object.cast [as as] (http://localhost:53122/dart_sdk.js:4626:17)
at Function.as_C [as as] (http://localhost:53122/dart_sdk.js:4271:19)
at http://localhost:53122/dart_sdk.js:15079:98
at Function._insertionSort (http://localhost:53122/dart_sdk.js:23099:55)
at Function._doSort (http://localhost:53122/dart_sdk.js:23086:24)
at Function.sort (http://localhost:53122/dart_sdk.js:23068:22)
at Array.[dartx.sort] (http://localhost:53122/dart_sdk.js:15079:26)
at RxList.new.sort (http://localhost:53122/packages/get/src/rx/rx_impl.dart.lib.js:610:27)
at home_controller.HomeController.new.getProductsFromController (http://localhost:53122/packages/site_catalogo_modelo/controllers/home_controller.dart.lib.js:94:21)
at product_controller.ProductController.new.getProducts (http://localhost:53122/packages/site_catalogo_modelo/controllers/home_controller.dart.lib.js:212:74)
at getProducts.next (<anonymous>)
at http://localhost:53122/dart_sdk.js:37340:33
at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:53122/dart_sdk.js:37194:58)
at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (http://localhost:53122/dart_sdk.js:32178:29)
at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:53122/dart_sdk.js:32725:49)
at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:53122/dart_sdk.js:32763:17)
at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:53122/dart_sdk.js:32606:23)
at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (http://localhost:53122/dart_sdk.js:32628:35)
at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:53122/dart_sdk.js:37455:13)
at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:53122/dart_sdk.js:37461:13)
at http://localhost:53122/dart_sdk.js:32980:9
```

Comment: Can you give me the whole code, like what you store whole value **products**, and also, why don't you try doing this `products.sort()` and see if that is what you want? It looks interesting to me, we can work on this together, just give me some more data :)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code presented; [it works fine in DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ee0914f66ddd308b13c2d328052fedeb).  Are you sure that this is the relevant code and that you copied and pasted it exactly?

Comment: I just updated the code adding the whole class and simulating the process, I just add the data from firestore on the list of products, the thing is when I try to compare those two string that is a DateTime substringed.

Comment: I still don't see anything wrong with your code (other than a missing semicolon when you use `products.addAll`, which I presume is a transcription error.) Please post a minimal, complete, *verifiable* example.  The process of creating a reproducible example also might help you debug the problem yourself.

Comment: What do you get when you do `products.sort()` only @djalmafreestyler?

Comment: I am trying to compare this String ("2020-07-21 12:31:13") with this String ("2020-07-21 12:31:08"), and get the newest and put on the top of the list, that's what I needed but I have this error, I don't think that's necessary to put a code that retrieves data from Firestore since I am showing the data I'm comparing.

Comment: @Alok `products.sort()` wouldn't work since `Product` does not implement the `Comparable` interface.

Comment: @Alok it doesn't work too, same error.

Comment: I am confused, if the `print(products[0].updatedAt)` and `print(products[1].updatedAt)` works fine, then why is it throwing this error => **Error: Expected a value of type 'Comparable<dynamic>', but got one of type 'Product'** in doing `compareTo` @jamesdlin.

Comment: @djalmafreestyler `String` already implements the `Comparable` interface.  Your problem lies elsewhere.  Please create a minimal, reproducible example.   That does not mean that you need to show your Firestore code; it means that you need to make a *simplified* example (for example, compare against the DartPad example I linked to).

Comment: @jamesdlin It worked now, the problem was that I was not using List<Product>, I am using Get lib for state managament, my products list was an observable which has the List itsefl inside another variable,because of this the sort of not working as it should, plus I had to change to 'b.updatedAt.compareTo(a.updatedAt))' to get the list in the order I needed. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was not using List, I was using [get package](https://pub.dev/packages/get) for state managament, my products list was an observable which has the List itsefl inside another variable, because of this the sort was not working as it should, plus I had to change to 'b.updatedAt.compareTo(a.updatedAt))' to get the list in the order I needed.